# Server Running but unable to log in to it

Tags: windows-server-2003, sql-server

I have a Windows Server 2003 server that is running sql server. Users can access the databases running on it fine, but I am unable to log on to it by remote desktop or directly at the machine. I am able to view the event logs remotely and I can't see anything that shouts out as being a problem.

What options can people think of for regaining access to this server or finding out more information about the problem?

I am able to reinstall the operating system but would like to leave that as a last resort.

Comment: Is there some error message when logging in directly at the machine?  Does this persist after a reboot (assuming it's a machine you are ok with rebooting)?

Comment: I am not able to log in to it directly which is the problem

Answer (score 1):

If you have proper credentials with sufficient privileges you can try to install the Remote Agent from [Dameware NT Utilities](http://www.dameware.com/downloads/) (30 days trial) and then log on the server to fix the Remote Desktop settings.